# How to destroy and create same gameobject in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to move my player to destroy monsters and the first time I destroy a monster I have the following error:

> MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'GameObject' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it.
>   Your script should either check if it is null or you should not destroy the object.

How can I make it to duplicate itself as a new GameObject?

This is my script:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TimeMap: MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject selectedUnit;

    public GameObject selectedMonster;
    public TileType[] tileTypes;

    try{
        if(selectedMonster.GetComponent<Monster>().tileX == selectedUnit.GetComponent<Unit>().tileX && selectedMonster.getComponent<Monsters>().tileY == selectedUnit..GetComponent<Unit>())
            Destroy(selectedMonster);

    }

    public void SpawnMon() {
        if(counter % 5 == 0){
            Debug.Log(" counter % 5 == 0");
            Instantiate(selectedMonster.GetComponent<Monsters>().Monster, new Vector3(Random.Range(1,8), Random.Range(1,8), -1), Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }
}
```

So I try to create the same object or a clone of it every 5 moves, but I am having errors while doing it.

Comment: Please do not post screenshot of your code. Post the code instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Problems:**

You are trying to access your monsters like this:

`selectedMonster.GetComponent<Monster>()`

It means if you have in your scene more than one GameObject of type Monster, Unity will not be sure which one you are referring to.

Also when you instantiate a monster, you use just

```
Instantiate(selectedMonster.GetComponent<Monsters>().Monster, new Vector3(Random.Range(1,8), Random.Range(1,8), -1), Quaternion.identity);
```

So you will not be able to distinguish one instance from another in your scene.

**Solutions:**

In case you wanted to continue with this approach, where you check if tileX and tileY of monster match with your Unit (which I assume is your hero or similar), you should have all monsters inside an array so you can iterate them all in a way you refer easily to the one you want to destroy.

You could try [FindObjectsOfType](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectsOfType.html) and there pass your Monster type:

```
Monster [] monsters= FindObjectsOfType(typeof(Monster )) as Monster [];
```

Then you iterate

```
foreach (Monster thisMonster in monsters){
   //check things here
}
```

Another option is to store the monsters in an array when you instantiate them

```
//Define as global variable a list of Monsters
List<GameObject> monsterList = new List<GameObject>();

//Then you instantiate then like
monsterList .add((GameObject)Instantiate(selectedMonster.GetComponent<Monsters>().Monster, new Vector3(Random.Range(1,8), Random.Range(1,8), -1), Quaternion.identity));
```

And you iterate them using the foreach as before

**Better Solution (From my point of view)**

However, since your main goal, correct me if I am wrong, is to detect when the position of a Unit match with the position of a monster, to later destroy that particular monster. I would use [colliders](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html) instead. And in the GameObject you call Unit I would add a `TriggerEnter`. Since you use the TileX and TileY I suspect you are creating a 2D game, so it would be something like this:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) {
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
    }
```

With this you destroy any monster that touches your "Unit" and you will not have reference problems.